# Import .dae to .scn but it can't Move or animate in XCode8 SceneKit

Tags: scenekit

i have import a robot dae from blender

i can control (rotate the arm, lag, etc) the robot in unity, but i can't control the same thing in xcode8.

in xcode8 scenekit interface, i drag .dae to the scene and i can move/transform/change position to the .dae file.

but the other dae can do this.

i can rotate the other model with SCNAction or something but this robot.dae

is there is a hidden config in .dae and i must unlock to edit this model ??

this .dae change change is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57965179/robot.dae

================
update

just simple drag dae to scenekit

the model can't be move in scn edit windows

[the model can't be drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uxWt.png)

Comment: Please post enough of your code that we can reproduce your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: update a simple image for that, there is no need any swift code, the model can't be change position in scn view.

Comment: full code is here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57965179/SpriteKitTest.zip

Answer (score 0):

This is late and may not be relevant, but I ran into the same problem and this is how I fixed it...

Basically, the model provided to me was rigged, so the visible part of the model was not the parent part of the model. I was trying to move the part that was visible. After checking the scenegraph in the model.scnassets folder in Xcode, I noticed that the visible parts were children of a rigging piece called "Armature." When I referenced the model by that instead, everything worked beautifully!

You may be trying to move and rotate and invisible part of your asset.

Hope that helps.